# How to find a Pantone Color in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, pantone

I have a project which needs to be done in Pantone 18-2140 Carbaret color and I have no idea how to find it in illustrator. I went through all color books :(
 I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you,
Marta

Comment: `Color books > PANTONE…`

Comment: If you can't find it in any of your pre-installed colour books, maybe either Adobe or PANTONE will have additional colour books for your to download?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Adobe Creative Cloud you can just go on kulor and choose from hundreds of color-sets who have been created by all Creative Cloud users and from Adobe. You can also visible it in your panel in Photoshop/Illustrator/Indesign. You'll find your saved themes from the kulor site in *window > CC Library*

[[image: Color Themes in the Photoshop Panel]

[[image: Sorry that it is in german, but there you can visible the color panel in Photoshop]

1. Image: Color Themes in the Photoshop Panel
2. Image: Sorry that it is in german, but there you can visible the color panel in Photoshop CC.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know that all the default Pantones are availble in the menu *Window > Swatch Libraries > Color Books*.

**BUT the Pantone 18-2140 is in the TCX palette (*Pantone Fashion and Home* book).** It's not available by default to my knowledge.

If you are doing a print project, this color will most likely be converted anyway to a CMYK recipe or a standard coated/uncoated Pantone equivalent.

## Options:

**You can download the library *if* you purchased the Pantone book associated with that color:**

http://pantone.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1798/related/1

**Or you can convert that Pantone to another Pantone book already available in the Adobe's software.**

The best way to do this is by using the coated and uncoated Pantone paper book AND comparing with the Pantone Fashion and Home book to find a close match. The coated version might be easier to use for this.

Here are some links with tips on how to do it "digitally" if you don't have the 2 Pantone books:

[How to convert Pantone 7C to TPX?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/58773/how-to-convert-pantone-7c-to-tpx/58829#58829)

[How To Convert Pantone Tint to similar Pantone Color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63160/how-to-convert-pantone-tint-to-similar-pantone-color/63164#63164)

---

**If you are working on a project that absolutely requires you to use that exact Pantone**, you can simply use a very close CMYK color recipe (or another Pantone) and rename your Spot Color to that Pantone name; to a printer or a manufacturer, it doesn't matter what's the name of the Pantone or even the color value you used, as long this color is in Spot Color in Illustrator. To know what ink and process the printer will use, you'll need to ask the printer!

[What does it mean when printers have told me my colour is not a Pantone colour, but in my file it is?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63135/what-does-it-mean-when-printers-have-told-me-my-colour-is-not-a-pantone-colour/63137#63137)

---

## RGB/Hex... meh

Unless you plan on doing ONLY web projects, I do not recommend you convert this color to Hex or RGB because you will end up facing the issue of having to convert this color again to CMYK or another Pantone...

It's far easier to convert from CMYK/Pantone to RGB/Hex than the opposite.

Answer (score -3):

you can try #D03377, more information you can find here : http://color2u.cocolog-nifty.com/color4u/2012/03/pantone-tpx-col.html

Comment: Why #D...? Suppose your given link does not work. Then your answer is unclear.  Please add an explanaition here ...

Comment: This "#D03377" means the code of Pantone 18-2140 Carbaret, and Marta asked how she can find this colour in illustration I gues she will understand very well what does it means.

Comment: #D03377 is, I suppose, only an approximation of the PANTONE ink in RGB colour space. By converting it into CMYK (prompting additional conversion errors and inaccuracies), you can print something that looks like it, but not the ink itself. Downvote.

Comment: Using a hexadecimal approximation of a Pantone colour is (unless you're working exclusively for digital output) a terrible idea.