# How to convert Pantone 7C to TPX?

Tags: color, print-design, color-conversion, color-reproduction

How do I convert Pantone 7C (Cool Gray) to TPX?

Is C a color international standard for print graphics?

[image]

Comment: @user49050 C means Coated in Pantone colors. No idea about TPX though.

Comment: Pantone colors can't really be converted to anything. It'd be up to the other code standard to decide what their version would be.

Comment: Oh wait. I had to google TPX. So TPX *is* a pantone identifier. I'm not sure how how--or even if--you can convert Pantone colors from print inks to textiles automatically. Might be a question you need to send to Pantone directly. (Also, Ryan is correct. C = coated paper. U = uncoated paper)

Answer (score 4):

The TPX ink s are used on textile and paints. There's some converter online but apparently you won't always find a good match there; some Pantones don't have an exact equivalent in TPX.

http://www.pantone.com/pages/pantone/colorfinder.aspx

So the best way to find the equivalent of you TPX in Pantone will be to use a Solid Coated Pantone color book and compare it with a TPX swatch book, ideally a printed one.

You can ask your printer for this or check the "Pantone Fashion + Home Paper" to find it manually online in the cross libraries. This might not be the most precise way but that's the book you're looking for.

## Here's a converter from Pantone for cross libraries:

http://www.pantone.com/pages/pantone/color_xref.aspx

## And here is the result it shows for your Solid Cool Gray 07 Coated:

First you select the color you have already from that library. In your case "Pantone solid coated."

Then the number of the Pantone.

Then the library you want it to be converted to. In your case, "Fashion Home."

[image: Convert pantone to TPX paint]