# Pantone TPX to PMS color conversion with accuracy. Is it possible?

Tags: color-conversion, pantone

I have been searching around to find a program that will convert Pantone TPX to PMS so my printer can test some screen printing.  I am not having much luck. **I have come to this community to ask if all colors from other Pantone libraries can be converted to PMS.**  My two colors that need to be converted to PMS are:

1. PANTONE 19-0201 TPX Asphalt
2. PANTONE 15-0146 Green Flash

Online conversion links are appreciated.

Comment: Hum. I deleted my comment becouse the color code is not the same as the normal pantone swaches. You are probably using a specific industry color guide.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but... Isn't PANTONE and PMS ('Pantone Matching System') exactly the same? *stumped is*

Comment: My first reaction was the same, but the color code is for interior design I belive.

Comment: Wether this is possible or not depends on the definition of what is accurate. Panatones can have different metamers than your preview.

Comment: No easy answer here: It's a relative conversion so you just have to eyeball it.

Comment: @Vincent I thought the same thing until my printer told me otherwise.

Comment: Possible reference: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64144/printing-on-plastic-coated-versus-uncoated/64171#64171

Answer (score 1):

There is a Pantone App called Color Xref for $1.99 that will help convert any Pantone color from one guide to the closest recommended color from another Pantone Color guide. For instance, Pantone 19-0201 TPX would be Pantone 425 C (in the solid coated formula guide) It's been a huge help for me in a lot of types of design. I've even used it to go from a Pantone Cotton TCX swatch to a Solid Coated swatch and then used the CMYK and RGB values when available, for digital applications and in-house test prints. But, one caveat, I usually use it as a starting point. Sometimes it's dead on, but the best practice is always to have the physical swatch guides and good natural or full spectrum light to let your eyes make the final call.

Here's a link to the app if you care to check it out:

[Pantone Color Xref](https://www.pantone.com/x-ref)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

At [www.pantone.com/x-ref](http://www.pantone.com/x-ref) you can put in any pantone swatch type, inks, dyes on cotton etc and convert it to another. If you are screen printing on t-shirts, better get free color swatches of actual material from the shirt manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

My recomendation is that you simply use the Pantone.com website. https://www.pantone.com/color-finder

Just typing that into google the result is this: https://www.pantone.com/color-finder/19-0201-TPX and https://www.pantone.com/color-finder?q=15-0146

But it seems that it has no equivalent for example on the bridge color guide, It has no CMYK correspondence.

I do not know if the chip has some aditional reflective property, like a metalic finish or translucency, but you probably can use the rgb values to find a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely be safer doing a conversion by looking at two charts. You seem to be using Pantones that relate to another industry than graphic design but you will need to check in the proper "end" chart which color looks closest. That is, if you are looking for a conversion to print on coated paper vs. uncoated, etc.

I also don't know which use you are making of your original code (is it on a fabric of some kind?) Try to take the material into account as it can change the color quite a bit!

To answer the overarching question of "Can all Pantones be converted to PMS?", it does seem to me like it's all the same system but the materials differ and reproduction means differ so I don't think it's possible to convert all Pantones of an industry to another industry. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found a decent TCX to CMYK conversion page. Hope this helps.

http://color2u.cocolog-nifty.com/color4u/2014/02/pantone-tcx-1.html

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE!  Suppose your given link is broken your link only answer is completly useless ...  Please add in own word what to do to solve the given problem, maybe by adding screenshot(s) ...